Trying to understand kernel optimization in CUDA. These changes had negligable effect
I have a CUDA Mandelbrot kernel, one which passes in the standard way:
__global__ void mandelbrot_worker(uint32_t* count_arr, uint32_t w, uint32_t h,
                                  const uint32_t max_count, const float xmin,
                                  const float xmax, const float ymin, const float ymax) {
    // Calculate global thread coordinates in the 2D Mandelbrot set grid
    int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  // x-coordinate
    int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;  // y-coordinate

    // if (i >= h || j >= w) {
    //     printf("ERROR: OUT OF BOUNDS");
    //     return;
    // } // Bounds check

    // Map pixel coordinate (i, j) to complex plane coordinates (x, y)
    float x0 = xmin + (xmax - xmin) * j / w;
    float y0 = ymin + (ymax - ymin) * i / h;

Commenting out the if statement to check for a thread that is out of bounds changed nothing. In this case, passing in
w = 3840*8
h = 2160*8

the condition is never executed.
But I assumed that removing the if statement would change the timings a bit. It might have, but obviously the loop in Mandelbrot is the biggest part.
I also thought that computing x0 and y0 is inefficient and passed in:
__global__ void mandelbrot_worker2(uint32_t* count_arr, uint32_t w, uint32_t h,
                                  const uint32_t max_count, const float xmin,
                                  const float dx_per_pixel, const float ymin, const float dy_per_pixel) {
    // Calculate global thread coordinates in the 2D Mandelbrot set grid
    int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  // x-coordinate
    int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;  // y-coordinate

    // Map pixel coordinate (i, j) to complex plane coordinates (x, y)
    float x0 = xmin + dx_per_pixel * j ;
    float y0 = ymin + dy_per_pixel * i ;

The maximum iteration is 64, so perhaps it's just a small percentage.
Last, it seems like optimization is always on for CUDA? The -O3 flag affects the host side a lot, but does not seem to impact code speed on CUDA at all.
So the questions are:

Do floating point terms get rearranged in CUDA unlike C?
Does pulling the constant out of the kernel do anything? Forget this instance, where the loop takes most of the time.
Is there any further compiler options that will generate better code?
We were just using nvcc -O3 mandel.cu

Last, does this code write sequentially to memory, do they try to schedule it that way, or is it random order since the threads do what they want? One idea that came to mind is to have a thread write values to 8 registers and then write them all at once.

Your observation about -O3 is correct and documented, i.e. it applies only to host code. Device code is optimized by default which can only be (somewhat) avoided using the -G (device debug) flag.

You should always specify your GPU architecture to the compiler to get architecture-specific optimizations.


the condition is never executed.

This is dependent of the kernel configuration (i.e. number of thread and block for each dimension). Generally, people use a number of thread that is divisible by the size of a warp which is 32 (so far on all devices). Since w and h are divisible by 32, there is no problem. Also note that conditions are generally cheap unless some threads are inactive due to predication. Last but not least, the main computing loop should take most of the time anyway so you should not care about this part.
Note the number of iteration is dependent of the location in Mandelbrot. This has huge implications. For a significant part of the set, z will never converge in a reasonable time (nor diverge). In some regions, this is noisy and warp divergence is a problem. Remapping is the key to increase the number of active threads. You need to profile your code to see which part of your code are efficient or not (Nsight is really great for that).

Do floating point terms get rearranged in CUDA unlike C?

No, unless you manually request it. The same thing it true in C (at least on mainstream compilers). -ffast-math on Clang and GCC enable this as well as many other optimisations assuming no NaN or Inf (which can be potentially dangerous regarding your target application). IEEE-754 compliance is AFAIK guaranteed on NVCC by default.

Does pulling the constant out of the kernel do anything? Forget this instance, where the loop takes most of the time.

I am not sure to understand but using constants for w and h can significantly improve performance of the division for example. Using constants is not always faster though: it depends of the actual computation done. The benefit for multiplications and addition is small if any (except is some very specific cases). For the number of iteration, it help the compiler to fully unroll (when the number is reasonably small).

Is there any further compiler options that will generate better code? We were just using nvcc -O3 mandel.cu

Fast-math can help. That being said, you can optimize the code yourself so it is not even needed. The idea is to use as much as possible FMA operations instead of just multiplication or addition alone.

does this code write sequentially to memory

Threads are executed by warp (32 threads) and they do SIMD packed loads/stores (i.e. contiguous) when memory accesses are coalesced. This is critical for performance. Warp scheduling is hardware-dependent. The size of the blocks can sometime impact performance.
What matter for performance is to do coalesced loads/stores, if possible with all threads being active (otherwise the bandwidth is simply wasted). Caching can also help but, here, the output size is so big that you cannot benefit from that.

Mandelbrot is generally compute-bound so you should care about minimizing the number of operations in the main loop (memory-related optimizations are not very useful except when the number of iteration is small which is rare in average). Loop unrolling can help to achieve that. Merging MULs+ADDs to FMAs operations too. Moreover, warp divergence is a critical issue on Mandelbrot you should reduce as much as possible to ensure all SIMD units are efficiently used. As stated before, remapping is an efficient solution for that. You can detect some patterns to avoid a lot of iterations too (rather complicated in practice). On top of that, like for all CUDA kernel, you should check the occupancy to maximize the performance of the kernel. Moreover, as pointed out by @paleonix in comments, instruction pipelining (sometime considered as instruction-level parallelism) can also be a way to improve performance on GPUs (even with a relatively bad occupancy) though it is certainly hard to benefit from this on a Mandelbrot kernel.

"No, unless you manually request it." Merging multiplication and addition into FMAs is activated by default in CUDA (while deactivated by default on the CPU), see this answer

Especially with compute-bound kernels going for maximum occupancy is not necessarily ideal. When unrolling loops one needs a lot of registers and lower occupancy helps with that (assuming you let the compiler know about your needs using e.g. launch bounds).

"Merging multiplication and addition into FMAs is activated by default in CUDA" I know but my point is that you can change the mathematical operations a bit so to better benefit from FMA. The compiler can generally not do that (at least they did not last time I checked for Mandelbrot and other similar codes, using both Clang and NVCC). Maybe it wasn't clear enough in my answer.

Regarding the occupancy, my point is to maximize performance, not occupancy ;) . But yes, good point, unrolling can sometimes make things worst. One need to test and check the occupancy and the resulting performance. I've seen cases where having a slightly worst occupancy and use more register so to do some advanced optimizations was better than minimizing the number of register resulting in an optimal occupancy. When the occupancy is already good, the performance gain tends to be small and using more registers/shared-memory remove some instructions can be better. This is arch-dependent though

People often refer to these ancient slides which say that low occupancy + ILP gives better performance than high occupancy. But I have not verified this claim for recent hardware.

@paleonix This is very interesting. AFAIK (Nvidia) GPUs execute instructions in-order and one at a time so this is not really ILP but pipeline (instruction latency is hidden with more instructions). At least, this is true for pre-Volta GPUs, because since Volta the GPUs can run instructions on both the integer unit and the FPUs simultaneously though I am not sure this is really done at the same cycle. Tests and informations I gathered so far tends to indicate instructions are still executed in-order and it is not easy to measure when instructions are really executed.

While I found similar results showing pipelining can help to hide latency (especially for memory bound codes) during optimizations and tests, I was supersized by the claim that pipelining can be as efficient than multi-threading for hiding latency so I did some tests on my Nvidia 1660 Super GPU. Results shows that pipelining can make the FMA code (with 64 threads) only twice faster (2x throughput). Multithreading too. However, pipelining is fragile and requires >= 16x instructions per loop to reach that (8x only results in a 1.5x boost) while multithreading nearly reach that with 2x threads.

@paleonix When doing more advanced tests and measurements, I found out that FMA (and ADD) instructions should take 4 cycle of latency and 2 cycle of throughput. This is why latency-hiding can only results in a twice faster code on my GPU architecture. Besides, the compilers tends to shuffle instruction in a way that is, I think, not optimal and this is certainly why a huge unrolling factor is unfortunately required to get a good speed up (any stall is critical for performance). On should consider the significant number of additional register needed with such unrolling factor.

@paleonix This is still OK for some code like matrix-multiplication and FFT which can benefit from register tiling (more registers means less memory-related instructions like less loads and less indexing-related ones). This can also be a good solution to speed-up some loops in kernels having several loops and where the occupancy may never be optimal for all loops (simultaneously).

@paleonix At least 128 threads per SM are still needed on my GPUs to use it efficiently (even with 16 independent instructions per loop), possibly 2 blocks of 2 warps. This matches with the fact that there is AFAIK 4 SIMD FPU each capable to execute 1 warp' instructions every 2 cycle (4 cycle of latency). With dependent instructions, we should use 256 threads (2x more threads are needed to hide latency). Independent Instructions of 1 unique warp does not seems to be scheduled on multiple SIMD units (hence no real ILP and just a better pipelining) based on the experimental results.

@paleonix Overall the latency of FP instructions tend to reduce over GPU generations so I would argue that pipelining should not play a much more significant role on more recent and future GPUs, except maybe for memory instructions though memory bandwidth tends to be a limiting factor on all mainstream CPU/GPU architectures (see Memory Wall). As for the 128 threads per SM, this is AFAIK still true on newer GPU (I fact, I wonder if this is not higher on some recent server-side GPU architecture). Sorry for the very-long comments but I think it's worth sharing these results/information :) !

I enjoyed reading about your experiments. Maybe just incorporate them into the answer?

@paleonix I think this is a bit too far from the original question and certainly not very useful for Mandelbrot so I just added a sentence about it.

@paleonix Note I made some additional tests on another kernel regarding the benefit of pipelining memory instructions. It turns out I succeed to make a kernel almost twice faster thank to that. Using a lot of threads and blocks was not enough to saturate memory in my case while increasing the number of concurrent VRAM loads (with many blocks and 96 threads/block) was. The problem was stalls due to the VRAM load latency. I unrolled the loop 10 times (the compiler did not reorder loads although it could) and then manually reorder memory instructions to execute them as early as possible.

@paleonix This resulted in a significantly lower "long-scoreboard stalls" (with the same occupancy) and higher memory saturation confirming the hypothesis. I also can see that too much memory concurrence seems a bit detrimental to performance like in the shared pdf. I think this method is pretty good to improve codes that are latency-bound due to memory operations on modern GPUs. I wonder if this applies to shared memory.

I would think so. Just that one needs less unrolling as the latencies are smaller.
